# Multi Lang., need to change text on radio button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to change text on the radio button.

Currently there is the text in English and required it to change in Arabic language.

Any information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to read about Globalization and Localization on ASP.NET.
Refer to the following please:

[ASP.NET Globalization and Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx).

[Globalization and localization demystified in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Kb/aspnet/localizationByVivekTakur.aspx)

[ASP.NET 2.0 Globalization & Localization solution](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Internationalization.aspx)